# How to serve woff2 files from owin FileServer

Tags: mime-types, owin, font-awesome, fileserver, woff2

Since font awesome 4.3, they added the fonts as woff2 format.

I'm guetting 404ed when trying to serve this file through owin :

```cs
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions() {
    RequestPath = PathString.Empty,
    FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@"banana")
});
```

How do I serve woff2 mime type files through file server in owin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the not-very-nice casting by using inheritance:

```
FileServerOptions options = new FileServerOptions
{
    StaticFileOptions =
    {
        ContentTypeProvider = new CustomFileExtensionContentTypeProvider(),
    }
};
```

where

```
private class CustomFileExtensionContentTypeProvider : FileExtensionContentTypeProvider
{
    public CustomFileExtensionContentTypeProvider()
    {
        Mappings.Add(".json", "application/json");
        Mappings.Add(".mustache", "text/template");
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a really nice way since it makes it easy to add types in the future. Both answers were useful to me but I ended up using this one to fix my problem.

Answer (score 9):

Two possibilities :

- Serve all kind of file types :

```cs
var options = new FileServerOptions() {
    RequestPath = PathString.Empty,
    FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@"banana")
};

options.StaticFileOptions.ServeUnknownFileTypes = true;

app.UseFileServer(options);
```

- Add woff2 mime type :

```cs
var options = new FileServerOptions() {
    RequestPath = PathString.Empty,
    FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@"banana")
};

((FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)options.StaticFileOptions.ContentTypeProvider)
    .Mappings.Add(".woff2", "application/font-woff2");

app.UseFileServer(options);
```

Second options seems not as elegant but is nonetheless the best. Read [why mime types are important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types).